# Why are TypeScript's IterableIterator<> and Generator<> generics slightly different?

Tags: typescript, iterator, generator

In TypeScript (3.6.3) *Generator<>* is almost identical to *IterableIterator<>*. When *Generator<>* extends *Iterator<>*, it defaults the third generic argument *(TNext)* to *unknown*. *Iterator<>* by itself defaults *TNext* to *undefined*. So *Generator* and *Iterator* (and *IterableIterator*) don't line up as well as they might should.

```
let gen2:IterableIterator<string>;

function* gen1():Generator<string> {
    yield* gen2;
}
```

The yield* line is an error: "Cannot delegate iteration to value because the 'next' method of its iterator expects type 'undefined', but the containing generator will always send 'unknown'. ts(2766)".

Am I missing something? Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there was a thread buried somewhere in the TypeScript github issues that might explain the discrepancy. I don't know the reason myself, but I would like to point out that if you remove the `: Generator<string>` and let TypeScript infer the return type itself, it's `Generator<string, void, undefined>`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is actually a very complicated issue. I do not pretend to understand it fully. But perhaps I can offer some insight.

## Why did they add them?

(in [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/e8bf9584aa74aabfecb51a02edb13e3657508274#diff-5c3d60d8ed16d2857e28a35a61302b48)).
Typescript decided, for better or for worse, it wants stricter type checks for generators. There are actually some valid reasons for this. Take the following example

```
function* foo() {
    let m = 0;
  
    while (m < 10) {
      yield m++;
    }
    
    return "done";
}

let gen = foo(),
    curr;

while(!(curr = gen.next()).done) {}

// At his point we should know that 
// curr.value is a string because curr.done is true
```

Here we can see the problem — we can't know if a value was returned or yielded yet by all rules of logic we should. So they introduced TReturn. TNext was [introduced](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30790) to:

> […] correctly check, and provide a type for, the result of a `yield` expression based on the next type of the generator's return type annotation (i.e. the `TNext` type in the `Generator` definition above).

## Why the default values?

Now, if you have decided to make such changes you are probably going to break some code — the goal is to break as little as possible.

We must note, there are idiomatic differences in the use of the `next()` function in generators and non-generator iterators. As the [ECMA-262 remarks](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-iterator-interface) for iterators.

> Arguments may be passed to the `next` function but their interpretation and validity is dependent upon the target Iterator. The for-of statement and other common users of Iterators do not pass any arguments, so Iterator objects that expect to be used in such a manner must be prepared to deal with being called with no arguments.

Iterators are predominantly used in for-of loops which do not pass an argument to next. Indeed, it is vary rare to pass an argument to the next function (MDN even calls it a "A zero-argument function"). Therefore the only sensible option for the default value of `TNext` would be `undefined`. Making it `unknown` would be a great hindrance to type checking (not to mention code compiled with `--strictNullChecks`).

That would all be great if passing an argument to the `next()` function with generators wasn't a pretty common practice — it actually has a valid use case… and defined behavior in [the standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-generator.prototype.next):

> ### Generator.prototype.next(*value*)
>
> The `next` method performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Let *g* be the **this** value.
> 2. Return ?GeneratorResume(*g*, *value*, empty).

and in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next):

> The value to send to the generator.
>
> The value will be assigned as a result of a `yield` expression. For example, in `variable = yield expression`, the value passed to the `.next()` function will be assigned to `variable`.

Not to mention, in a typical use case, the first `.next()` call would be called without an argument and subsequent ones will be called with. Unfortunately, there is no way to specify "optional first time, unknown subsequent times" kind of type, so I guess in light of all this they settled for `unknown` for the `TNext` in Generators.

Of course there is no perfect situation. But they have to settle for what they believe would be least problematic.

All those problems are discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2983) for anyone interested.