# How to yield* arrays in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, async-await, generator

I have a generator method that adds asyncronously some stuff to an array and at the end yields each member with `yield* array` like so:

```
while (!done) {
      await promise;
      yield* results; //<-- the array
      results = [];  //its emptied so as to not to yield dupes
      done = !this.#eventsListened.has(eventName);
    }
```

However our friendly neighbor tsc reports an error and I can't even begin to understand it or how to fix it. Can anybody explain what does this error mean and how am I supposed then to yield the contents of an array?

> TS2766: Cannot delegate iteration to value because the 'next' method
>   of its iterator expects type 'undefined', but the containing generator
>   will always send 'unknown'.

**Edit:** the whole generator function follows

```
  /**
   * Returns an iterator that loops over caught events
   * @yields Promise<Event|CustomEvent>
   */
  async *on(eventName: string, options?: AddEventListenerOptions): AsyncGenerator<Event> {
    if (this.#eventsListened.has(eventName)) {
      return;
    }
    let results: Event[] = [];

    let resolve: (value?: PromiseLike<Event> | Event) => void;

    let promise = new Promise<Event>(r => (resolve = r));
    let done = false;
    this.#eventsListened.add(eventName);

    if (typeof options === 'object' && typeof options.once !== 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('options.once is not supported. Use EventTarget2.once instead');
    }
    const callback = (evt: Event) => {
      results.push(evt);
      resolve();
      promise = new Promise<Event>(r => (resolve = r));
    };

    this.addEventListener('eventName', callback, options);
    while (!done) {
      await promise;
      yield* results;
      results = [];
      done = !this.#eventsListened.has(eventName);
    }
    this.removeEventListener(eventName, callback);
  }
```

Comment: Did you really mean to use [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) or do you need a normal `yield`?

Comment: @VLAZ I really mean yield* I want to yield each member of the array individually

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568399/why-are-typescripts-iterableiterator-and-generator-generics-slightly-differ

Comment: More context is needed (mainly the `function*` definition).

Comment: The problem is that `.next(stuff)` will pass a value into the iterator, and as you `yield*` also into the array iterator. The array iterator is typed as `Iterator<void, T, undefined>` so you may only call it as `.next()`, however your generator function is typed differently (or not at all). Therefore the `.next(...)` calls clash.

Comment: @JonasWilms please see the edits, for the whole signature of the method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your main Problem is `AsyncGenerator<Event>` ... As you did not specify the third generic parameter, it's default value (`unknown`) is used, and `unknown` missmatches `undefined`.

The missmatch occurs because the inner iterator does not expect any values passed into the iterator via `next(value)`, therefore it's `TNext` generic parameter is `undefined`. As you `yield*` that iterator, calling `next(...)` on your generators iterator will call the inner iterator with the same arguments, therefore the arguments have to match.

Typescript infers the type of a generator function to `AsyncGenerator<..., ..., undefined>` for exactly that reason, and you should do that too (as long as you dont want to pass values into the iterator with `.next`): `AsyncGenerator<Event, void, undefined>`.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick... I didn't know the AsyncGenerator interface had three types. It still baffles me that you can send an iterator a value.